# Await or Task.FromResult

Tags: c#, .net, task-parallel-library, async-await

I have one service lets say,

```
public interface ISomeService
{
    Task<bool> DoSomeExpensiveCheckAsync(string parameter);
}
```

And I have this class to consume the service. It just needs to do some simple null checks and then return the service response back.

```
public class SomeServiceConsumer
{
    private readonly ISomeService _serviceClient;

    public SomeServiceConsumer(ISomeService serviceClient)
    {
        _serviceClient = serviceClient;
    }

    public async Task<bool> DoSomething1Async(string someParameter)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(someParameter))
        {
            return false;
        }
        return await _serviceClient.DoSomeExpensiveCheckAsync(someParameter);
    }

    //No async or await keywords   
    public Task<bool> DoSomething2Async(string someParameter)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(someParameter))
        {
            return Task.FromResult(false);
        }
        return _serviceClient.DoSomeExpensiveCheckAsync(someParameter);
    }
}
```

Should I do `DoSomething1Async` or `DoSomething2Async`?

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15444389/321035), I should not wrap with an unnecessary `await` but then I have to use `Task.FromResult(false)` for shortcircuiting as in `DoSomething2Async`

But according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19103343/321035) there are cases with `try/catch` and `using` statements where I actually should `await` before returning.

Am I correct in saying then, that

1. If I have to use `try/catch` or `using` then I should `await`
2. Otherwise do not `await` if you are only going to return. And use `Task.FromResult` for short circuiting

I like `DoSomething1Async` more, and want to do that everywhere if someone says it doesnt matter :).

Answer (score 18, accepted):

If you're worried about it, cache the `Task`:

```
static readonly Task<bool> falseTask = Task.FromResult(false);
```

The `async` keyword also wraps exceptions up in the returned `Task`, along with a proper stack trace. It's a tradeoff, safety of behavior for perf.

Lets look at the difference scenarios where each would be different:

```
async Task UseSomething1Async(string someParameter)
{
    // if IsNullOrWhiteSpace throws an exception, it will be wrapped in
    // the task and not thrown here.
    Task t1 = DoSomething1Async(someParameter);

    // rather, it'll get thrown here. this is best practice,
    // it's what users of Task-returning methods expect.
    await t1;

    // if IsNullOrWhiteSpace throws an exception, it will
    // be thrown here. users will not expect this.
    Task t2 = DoSomething2Async(someParameter);

    // this would never have been reached.
    await t2;
}
```

Just illustrating the point here -- `IsNullOrWhiteSpace` does not actually throw any exceptions for any reason.

As far as stack traces go, async stack traces are determined by where you `await`. No `await` means the method will disappear from the stack trace.

Say `DoSomeExpensiveCheckAsync` throws an exception. In the case of `DoSomething1Async`, the stack trace will look like `caller -> DoSomething1Async -> DoSomeExpensiveCheckAsync`.

In the case of `DoSomething2Async`, the stack trace would look like `caller -> DoSomeExpensiveCheckAsync`. Depending on the complexity of your code, this can make things difficult to debug.

In practice, I will generally only directly return a `Task` if I knew no exceptions would be thrown prior to it, and if the method name was merely an overload forwarding to another overload. There are always exceptions to this rule, there are bound to be places you want to maximize performance. Just pick and choose carefully, realize you might be making the life of you and your user harder.

Comment: Thanks Cory. I dont understand how it affects safety of behavior though. See my comment to @I3arnon's answer.

Answer (score 4):

**It doesn't really matter**. If you're comfortable with always marking `Task`-returning methods with the `async` keyword then go ahead and use `DoSomething1`.

As you said, it's a tradeoff:

- `DoSomething2` doesn't generate the state machine needed for an `async` method and so it's *slightly* faster (but the difference is mostly negligible).
- On the other hand it can have some unforeseen side effects regarding exception handling since in an `async` method the exception would be stored in the returned `Task` and in the other it would be thrown regularly.

Comment: I dont understand the exception difference @I3arnon. if I make DoSomeExpensiveCheckAsync in the service throw an explicit exception , then "var from1 = await someServiceCustomer.DoSomething1Async("Hello");" and "
                var from2 = await someServiceCustomer.DoSomething2Async("Hello");" throw the exact same exception. DoSomething1Async does have an extra TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess in the stacktrace though. That does show that DoSomething1Async is doing something extra, but I dont get the unforseen side effect part.

Comment: @labroo To understand the difference you need to think what would happen without an `await`: `var task = DoSomethingAsync("Hello")`. If there's an exception and the method is async this would not throw an exception. The exception would be stored in the task and rethrown on `await`. If the method isn't async the exception would be thrown just like any other method.

Answer (score -1):

To answer your own question, you need to ask yourself this question: *Which part of the method is the truly `async` part?* I think we can all agree that the truly `async` part is when the code `_serviceClient.DoSomeExpensiveCheckAsync` is called. Therefore, `DoSomething2Async` is more a hack than anything. According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228607.aspx):

> This method is useful when you perform an asynchronous operation that returns a Task object, and the result of that Task object is already computed.

So in other words if you had computed the result of the truly asynchronous part or you had it cached, you could use `Task.FromResult` on it. However, using `Task.FromResult(false)` would be lying and hacking the whole mechanism.

In some cases you may need to use `Task.FromResult` for doing work that's not truly asynchronous but the work may take a while because it is CPU intensive, in those cases one may make an exception to avoid freezing the UI.

In conclusion, `DoSomething1Async` is more appropriate.